# Word for something post-contextualisation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Let me use an analogy to clarify what I mean. You obtain 2000 user inputs from a survey. You have data. This data becomes information when it is processed, contextualized and understood in a particular setting. Is there a phrase / word communicative of this transition from data to information?

Comment: Your terms *process*, *contextualise* and *understand* are good candidates for the transition you describe.

Comment: The title asks for a word denoting the transformed data (which is _information_ as per the body of the question), the body asks for a word denoting the _transition_. Which one do you actually seek?

Answer (score 1):

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_pyramid) uses the word ***infer*** to describe the process of transforming data to knowledge.

They quote from *[Organizing Knowledge: An Introduction to Managing Access to Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_pyramid#cite_note-Rowley2-15)*:

> "Information is inferred from data"